# Two Column format with Nav & Content displaying PDF in Content without additional scroll bars

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've tried several combinations but have not found one yet that will display gracefully without adding unneeded scrolls bars.

I have a page that displays a Navigation column and then a content column.  In the content column I am displaying a PDF in an IFrame.  The left hand column is fixed at say 150px.  I need the the right hand column to consume the rest of the width of the page and all of the height of the page.  For some reason when the IFrame is put in the right hand div grows by about 5px and it adds an additional scroll bar that just mucks things up.  I can make the scroll bar go away using the overflow-y: hidden but that seems to be hack rather than the right thing to do.

I've tried it with both an iframe and object tags and the behavior is the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color:#808080;
        }
        
        div#nav
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 150px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color:#C0C0C0;
        }

        div#content
        {
            top: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            margin-left: 150px;
            background-color: #2F4F4F;
        }

        iframe#pdf
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <fieldset class="lookupFields">
            <div>
                <label for="book" >Book:</label>
                <input type="text" id="book" size="5" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="page">Page:</label>
                <input type="text" id="page" size="5" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="btnViewImage" value="View" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe id="pdf" frameborder="0" src="06500001-2.pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vch27/) based on your code.

The PDF seems to fit quite nicely and I don't get an extra scroll bar. The PDF page resizes with I change the size of the page (I'm using IE11).

I didn't change much in the HTML.

```
<div id="nav">
  <fieldset class="lookupFields">
    <div>
      <label for="book" >Book:</label>
      <input type="text" id="book" size="5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="page">Page:</label>
      <input type="text" id="page" size="5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="btnViewImage" value="View" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <iframe id="pdf" frameborder="0" src="http://www.historytools.org/sources/lincoln-gettysburg.pdf">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: In IE 11 and FF 29 I have two scrollbars along the right hand side.  One for adobe acrobat and one for the browser.  The browser one only scrolls about 5px.

Comment: Out of curiosity what version of Adobe PDF plugin are you using?  I've got 11.0.07.

Comment: It's either a jsfiddle built-in plug-in, or jsfiddle automatically calls my Adobe reader (doubtful).